# the collection of all cubes that intersect the complement of R

Tags: real-analysis

The exterior measure of  a rectangle R in $\mathbb{R^d}$ is equal to its volume. Consider a grid in $\mathbb {R^d}$ formed by cubes of side length $\frac1k$. Q' denotes the collection of all cubes that intersect both R and the complement of R. There comes the question:
**Why there are $O(k^{d-1})$ cubes in Q'?**

Comment: Um, aren't there infinitely many cubes that intersect the complement of $R$? Or do you mean to count cubes that intersect both $R$ and its complement?

Comment: @GregMartin YEAH.The textbook do not mention that it intersects R. But this should be added to.

Comment: Are the "faces" of the original rectangle parallel to the grid lines? Either way, the reason is basically because any such little cube must intersect one of the $(d-1)$-dimensional faces of $R$, and these can be considered separately. If we expand $R$ by a factor of $k$ instead of shrinking the grid by a factor of $k$, the ultimate reason for the given bound is that the "surface area" of any $(d-1)$-dimensional face is a constant times $k^{d-1}$.